# switch statement outputting default statement even when not needed

Tags: c++, switch-statement, default

When I run my code it will give the output to one of my cases, but will then also output the default statement even though it is not needed. I have no idea how to fix this. I have tried putting the default statement only in the last switch statement which makes it only output the default one time instead of multiple times, however it will still output the default statement once even when it doesn't need to.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x , b , t , s , p;
    cout << "Enter Type of Sport: 1.Biking 2.Camping 3.Hiking 4.Rock Climbing" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Mountain Bike 2.Road Bike" << endl;
            cin >> b;
            break;
        case 2: 
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.2-Person Tent 2.4-Person Tent" << endl; 
            cin >> t;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Summer Boots 2.Winter Boots" << endl;
            cin >> s;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Bouldering Pad 2.Top Rope Pad" << endl;
            cin >> p;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
    }

    switch(b) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Price of Mountain Bike is $500." << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: 
            cout << "Price of Road Bike is $400." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
    }

    switch(t) {
        case 1: 
            cout << "Price of 2-Person Tent is $200." << endl;
            break;
        case 2: 
            cout << "Price of 4-Person Tent is $300." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
    }

    switch(s) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Price of Summer Boots is $100." << endl;
            break;
        case 2: 
            cout << "Price of Winter Boots is $150." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
    }

    switch(p) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Price of Bouldering Pad is $100." << endl;
            break;
        case 2: 
            cout << "Price of Top Rope Pad is $60." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider moving the code that is specific to each sport to a function you can call. Right now it falls through all of the switches in a row even when that item was not chosen. Since your variables are not initialized what happens for those is anyone's guess.

Comment: What do you mean by function? Is there an example you can give me? I'm very new to coding.

Comment: Please learn to properly indent your code. It makes it much easier to follow the flow of execution, and also makes your code much easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: I had it properly indented but this website made me space everything 4 times from the left or else it wouldn't upload as code :)

Comment: My editor, vscode, like most programmer's editors will indent a whole file. Just hilight everything and hit tab.

Comment: it should be fixed now I edited it and added all the proper indents

Comment: @JakeFarthing: Note that you can also use three backtick characters to mark the start and end of the code. That way, you don't have to indent anything. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for further information. You can access that help page also by pressing the question mark when writing or editing a question.

Comment: thanks everyone for the tips on how to indent, but I already know how to indent and would really like some help with the actual problem. Thanks

Comment: Read the second sentence of the first comment again - it explains exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I read that but i'm not sure how to fix it because I don't know what function I need to use

Comment: @JakeFarthing see the answer I just posted

Comment: do you know how I would stop it from running through all of the options each time I run it? Doing the nested switch statements solved the problem of giving me multiple outputs but now once I select on option and get the price for it, it moves on and makes me select another option

Answer (score 2):

Your code has **undefined behavior**, because you are passing *uninitialized* variables to your `switch` statements.

If the user enters `1` on the 1st prompt, only the variables `x` and `b` are assigned values, but the code still tries to evaluate variables `t`, `s`, and `p` even though their values are *indeterminate*, so all of those secondary `switch` blocks have a very high probability of invoking their `default` cases.

Same for the other user selections.

To fix this, you need to nest your secondary `switch` blocks *inside* of each `case` of the 1st `switch` block, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input;
    cout << "Enter Type of Sport: 1.Biking 2.Camping 3.Hiking 4.Rock Climbing" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Mountain Bike 2.Road Bike" << endl;
            cin >> input;
            switch (input) {
                case 1: {
                    cout << "Price of Mountain Bike is $500." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    cout << "Price of Road Bike is $400." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.2-Person Tent 2.4-Person Tent" << endl; 
            cin >> input;
            switch (input) {
                case 1: {
                    cout << "Price of 2-Person Tent is $200." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    cout << "Price of 4-Person Tent is $300." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Summer Boots 2.Winter Boots" << endl;
            cin >> input;
            switch (input) {
                case 1: {
                    cout << "Price of Summer Boots is $100." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    cout << "Price of Winter Boots is $150." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
                    break;
               }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Bouldering Pad 2.Top Rope Pad" << endl;
            cin >> input;
            switch (input) {
                case 1: {
                    cout << "Price of Bouldering Pad is $100." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    cout << "Price of Top Rope Pad is $60." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As @RetiredNinja suggested, you can clean this up a bit, by defining a separate function to handle each sport individually, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void DoBiking();
void DoCamping();
void DoHiking();
void DoRockClimbing();

int main() {
    int input;
    cout << "Enter Type of Sport: 1.Biking 2.Camping 3.Hiking 4.Rock Climbing" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1: {
            DoBiking();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            DoCamping();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            DoHiking();
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            DoRockClimbing();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void DoBiking() {
    int input;
    cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Mountain Bike 2.Road Bike" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Price of Mountain Bike is $500." << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Price of Road Bike is $400." << endl;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void DoCamping() {
    int input;
    cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.2-Person Tent 2.4-Person Tent" << endl; 
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Price of 2-Person Tent is $200." << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Price of 4-Person Tent is $300." << endl;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void DoHiking() {
    int input;
    cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Summer Boots 2.Winter Boots" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Price of Summer Boots is $100." << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Price of Winter Boots is $150." << endl;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void DoRockClimbing() {
    int input;
    cout << "Choose type of Equipment : 1.Bouldering Pad 2.Top Rope Pad" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Price of Bouldering Pad is $100." << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Price of Top Rope Pad is $60." << endl;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also "case 1" vs "case '1'"

Comment: @John5342 the code is reading integers, not characters, so `case 1` is correct.

Comment: My apologies. Proof browsing at 3am is a bad idea XD